# cbind, vertically instead of horizontally

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to bind a list to a data frame in the below example.  I want the row number for each row, but instead I'm getting each row, and the entirety of the list.  It's just a simplification of what I'm trying to do but the principle is the same.

mtcars is a dataframe of 32 obs. of  11 variables

I'm looking to make it 32 obs of 12 variables where the new column is the list, instead I'm getting 32 obs of 43 variables

Any help would be really appreciated

```
the_list <- list()
for (i in 1:nrow(mtcars))
{
  the_list[i] <- i
}

test <- cbind(mtcars, the_list)
```

Comment: Don't use a list, use a vector instead. You can create a vector afterwards for instance, with `unlist`": `test <- cbind(mtcars, unlist(the_list))` or to just get a row number `test <- cbind(mtcars, seq_along(mtcars[, 1]))`.

Comment: `mtcars$row_number = 1:nrow(mtcars)` works?

Answer (score 0):

lmo's reply is the correct one.

test <- cbind(mtcars, unlist(the_list))

Answer (score 0):

If your rownames are just the numbers 1... nrow(), then simply do a :

```
mtcars %>% rownames_to_column(var='the_list')
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would want it to be a list instead of a vector like the other columns but the below works

```
mtcars$listCol <- as.vector(x = 1:nrow(mtcars), mode = "list")
```